# npm installed binaries not available from command line

Tags: nodejs, npm

I tried installing `babel-node` via `sudo npm install -g babel-node`. The binary for `babel-node` seems to be available in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-babel/node_modules/.bin/babel-node`, but this binary is not in my `$PATH`.

Is this expected behavior? If so, this is kind of annoying -- how can I get npm installed binaries available at the command line?

Maybe relevant: I installed both `nodejs` and `npm` via `apt-get`, and created a symbolic link from `nodejs` to `node`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you've been installing (or *think* you've been installing), but if you install the `babel` package —[per the documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/)— you'll get a `babel` binary in-path:

```
$ sudo npm install --global babel
...

$ which babel
/usr/local/bin/babel

$ readlink -f /usr/local/bin/babel
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel/bin/babel.js
```

Comment: Yep, definitely installed the wrong package. Thanks!